# Simple SQL query not working out

Tags: sql

[click here for database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVnWs.png)

Asked: Show for every department with at least 3 employees, the department's name and the amount of employees in that department born before 1967.

My code so far:

```
`Select department, department_name, numberofemployeesbefore1967 = ( select count(empleyee_id) from employee where year(dateofbirth) < 1967)
From employee inner join department on (department = department_id)
group by department, department_name
having count(*) >=3`
```

The output I have now: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VRzz.png)

I feel like this is a really easy one, but I cannot find how to show only the employees born before 1967 for that specific department.
Anyone to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the year in the main query and >=3 in a subquery

```
SELECT department department_name, count(*)
FROM department d
JOIN employee e on d.department_id = e.department
WHERE YEAR(dateOfBirth) < 1967 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE department = d.department_id) >= 3
GROUP BY d.id, d.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked the subquery like so...

`Select department, department_name, (select count(empleyee_id) from employee where year(dateofbirth) < 1967) AS numberofemployeesbefore1967
From employee inner join department on (department = department_id)
group by department, department_name
having count(*) >=3`